# input capacitor for buck converter

Tags: capacitor, dc-dc-converter, buck

To calculate the input capacitor for buck converter, I follow TI Application Report **[SLTA055–FEBRUARY 2006 "Input and Output Capacitor Selection"](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slta055/slta055.pdf)**.

It says to determine the input capacitor "**75 mVpp is recommended for maximum input voltage ripple. This will yield approximately 22 mVrms of ripple voltage**"

The question is how we select this value 75 mVpp?

thanks

Comment: Depends on your input current, switching frequency and inductor, as well as input impedance.

Comment: how can input current, switching frequency and inductor, as well as input impedance effect on selection of input voltage ripple?? I am looking for a formula or rule to select this

Comment: Said formula will be dependent on all above physical quantities, as well as ESR and ESL of your capacitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From section 1.1**

> As a general rule of thumb, keeping the peak to peak ripple amplitude
> below 75 mV **keeps the rms currents in the bulk capacitors within
> acceptable limits.**

Emphasis mine